# A funny kind of Ramsey number

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

A [shorter version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2742781/has-this-ramsey-type-function-been-studied) of this question was posted on Math Stack Exchange.

Let $V$ be a nonempty set. $(V,S)$ is a *graph* if $S\subseteq\binom V2,$ a *triple system* if $S\subseteq\binom V3,$
a *quadruple system* if $S\subseteq\binom V4.$

**Definition.** For lack of a better word, I will say that a triple system $(V,T)$ is *nice* if it satisfies any of the following conditions, which are easily seen to be equivalent:

- $\left|\binom X3\cap T\right|$ is even for every $X\in\binom V4;$
- there is a point $v\in V$ such that $\left|\binom X3\cap T\right|$ is even whenever $v\in X\in\binom V4;$
- there is a set $E\subseteq\binom V2$ such that $T=\left\{t\in\binom V3:\left|\binom t2\cap E\right|\text{ is odd}\right\};$
- there is a set $E\subseteq\binom V2$ such that $T=\left\{t\in\binom V3:\left|\binom t2\cap E\right|\text{ is even}\right\}.$

**Definition.** $f(n)$ is the least number $m$ such that, given any triple system $(V,T)$ with $|V|=m,$ we can find an $n$-element set $W\subseteq V$ such that the triple system $\left(W,T\cap\binom W3\right)$ is nice.
(In other words, for any $4$-element set $X\subseteq W,$ either all or none or half of the four $3$-element subsets of $X$ belong to $T.$)

> **Question 1.** Is there any literature on $f(n)$?
>   
> **Question 2.** What is $f(5)$?

Here are some trivial bounds for $f(n)$ in terms of ordinary Ramsey numbers.

**Definition.** The Ramsey number $R(n_1,n_2;d)$ is the least number $m$ such that, given an
$m$-element set $V$ and any set $S\subseteq\binom Vd,$ we can find a set $W\subseteq V$ such that either $|W|=n_1$ and $\binom Wd\cap S=\emptyset,$ or else $|W|=n_2$ and $\binom Wd\subseteq S.$

**Definition.** $g(n)$ is the least number $m$ such that, given any quadruple system $(V,Q)$ with $|V|=m,$ either we can find a $5$-element set $U\subseteq V$ such that $\left|\binom U4\cap Q\right|$ is even, or else we can find an $n$-element set $W\subseteq V$ and a point $v\in W$ such that $\left\{X:v\in X\in\binom W4\right\}\subseteq Q.$

**Definition.** $ES(n)$ is the least number $m$ such that any set of $m$ points in the plane, no three of which are collinear, contains the vertices of a convex $n$-gon.

**Easy upper bounds:**

$f(n)\le R(n,n;3).$

$f(4)=5\lt R(4,4;3)=13.$

$f(n)\le g(n)\le R(5,n;4).$

**Easy lower bounds**

$f(n)\ge ES(n)\ge2^{n-2}+1$ for $n\ge2.$

$f(R(m,n;2)+1)\ge R(m+1,n+1;3),$

in fact,

$f(R(m,n;2)+1)\ge f(h(m+1,n+1))\ge R(m+1,n+1;3),$

where $h(m+1,n+1)$ is defined in my other question [Another funny kind of Ramsey number](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304156/another-funny-kind-of-ramsey-number).