# Another funny kind of Ramsey number

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

**Definition.** $h(n_1,n_2)$ is the least number $m$ such that, if the edges of $K_m$ are colored with two colors, $1$ and $2,$ then for some color $i\in\{1,2\}$ there is a set $W\subseteq V(K_m)$ such that $|W|=n_i$ and every triangle in $W$ has an odd number of edges of color $i;$ **in other words,** for some $i\in\{1,2\},$ the graph consisting of the edges of color $i$ has an induced subgraph $H$ of order $n_i$ such that $H$ has at most two components, and each component of $H$ is a clique.

> **Question 1.** Is there any literature on $h(n_1,n_2)$ ?
>   
> **Question 2.** Is $h(4,5)=8$ ?

Here are some easy bounds for $h(n_1,n_2)$ in terms of ordinary Ramsey numbers.

**Definition.** The Ramsey number $R(n_1,n_2;d)$ is the least number $m$ such that, given an $m$-element set $V$ and any set $S\subseteq\binom Vd,$ we can find a set $W\subseteq V$ such that either $|W|=n_1$ and $\binom Wd\cap S=\emptyset,$ or else $|W|=n_2$ and $\binom Wd\subseteq S.$

**Definition.** As in my previous question [A funny kind of Ramsey number](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300018/a-funny-kind-of-ramsey-number), $f(n)$ is the least number $m$ such that, given an $m$-element set $V$ and any set $S\subseteq\binom V3,$ we can find an $n$-element set $X\subseteq V$ such that, for each $4$-element set $Y\subseteq X,$ we have $|\binom Y3\cap S|\equiv0\pmod2.$

**Upper bound:** $h(m+1,n+1)\le R(m,n;2)+1.$

**Lower bound:** $f(h(m,n))\ge R(m,n;3).$

Regarding $h(4,5),$ I know that $$8\le h(4,5)\le10.$$
On the one hand, $h(4,5)\le R(3,4;2)+1=10.$ On the other hand, to see that $h(4,5)\gt7,$ take a Hamiltonian cycle $C$ in $K_7$ and color the edges of $C$ with color $2$ and the rest with color $1.$ (This is the simplest of a whole bunch of $7$-point counterexamples.) I have not found a counterexample to the conjecture that $h(4,5)=8.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement $h(4,5)=8$ is true. It can be checked by enumerating all 8-vertex graphs (a total of 12346) and check them one by one.

For those who want to double-check, there are 48 graphs in which there is exactly one instance of $W$, and 43 in which there are two.

Comment: Could you provide some details on how to (efficiently) carry out a computation such as this? This is probably standard, so if instead there is a reference you'd recommend, I would be grateful.

Comment: The graphs are generated by B.D.Mckay's program geng, and the computation on a individual graph is brute-force: simply enumerate all the size-4 and size-5 sets of the graph, and test whether there is a clique or a union of two cliques.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In my (tedious and error-prone) pen-and-paper work, I seemed to find 19 7-vertex graphs with no instance of W. How close is that to the correct number?

Comment: My answer is 21. The graphs are shown in [here](https://imagebin.ca/v/47TNZ7kadNsc).